# SQL Case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, case-expression

```
SELECT MIN(Measurement),     
       (CASE 'NonDesMin'
          WHEN len(measurement) = 6 then '0000'
          ELSE '000'
        END) as [Min]    
  FROM LeachingView 
 WHERE DateTimeStamp > '2011-01-01' 
   AND measurement > 0
```

This is my SQL statement. I want to check the length of the field measurement, and if it is 6 characters long i want to display four 0's, else three 0's. i can getting an error:

> incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: Because the answer will be "no" if we don't ask: have you double-checked that your 'measurement' column is a CHAR (or varchar, or whatever) type?

Comment: len(measurement) and measurement > 0 used together. measurement seems to be string but is it guaranteed to be an integer as well?

Comment: @Adrian - SQL Server (from the "incorrect syntax near '='" message)

Comment: I was assuming that some other RDBMS could provide a similar message. Will retag as soon as available. Also, I fixed my answer since I was mixing aggregates with non-aggregates.

Comment: Are you using this to format a numeric value into a fixed number of digits? If so, there are better ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
select MIN(Measurement), 

    (Case 
        WHEN len(min(measurement)) = 6 then '0000'
        ELSE '000'
        END) as [Min]

from LeachingView 
where DateTimeStamp > '2011-01-01' and measurement > 0
```

Also, you were mixing aggregates with non-aggregates.

**Update**

You should just lose the `'NonDesMin'`. Explaining: when you enter a "variable" right after the `CASE`, you can have your `WHEN` clauses compare equality with your variable. So, your SQL could also be like that:

```
select MIN(Measurement), 

    (Case len(min(measurement))
        WHEN  6 then '0000'
        ELSE '000'
        END) as [Min]

from LeachingView 
where DateTimeStamp > '2011-01-01' and measurement > 0
```

That said, you use `CASE` in this format:

```
CASE SomeField
   WHEN 1 then 'One'
   WHEN 2 the 'Two'
   else 'Three or more'
end
```

Comment: I ended up finding out the answer, i posted it below. Thanks for the quick tutorial on case statements. i didn't end up using it but now i know

Answer (score 0):

```
select MIN(Measurement),
     (Case WHEN len(measurement) = 6 then '0000' ELSE '000' END) as [Min]
from LeachingView  where DateTimeStamp > '2011-01-01' and measurement > 0
```

Comment: Can't mix aggregates and non aggregates

Answer (score 0):

```
      (select min(measurement)
         from LeachingView 
         where measurement > 0 and inspectionid = RIGHT('000000000' + part_desc, 10)                     
             and datetimestamp > '2010-12-31'
  ) as [Non-Destructive Min],
```

Turns out i didnt even need a case statement, but this post helped me learn how to use them.
instead i just used code that added 10 0's the front of the number. then i took the right 8 characters. that is what this code did

```
  RIGHT('000000000' + part_desc, 10)
```

Thanks all for the post

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing you're wanting to append to to the beginning of Measurement.

```
SELECT CONCAT(Case WHEN LEN(Measurement) = 6 THEN '0000' ELSE '000' END, MIN(Measurement)) AS Measurement
FROM LeachingView 
WHERE DateTimeStamp > '2011-01-01' AND Measurement > 0;
```

Comment: You are mixing aggregates and non aggregates

Comment: Clearly I should stay away from SQL Server. It's been too long. Wow, I do not miss it!